# Sigma algebras...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

"Let $\mathcal{C}$ = {A,B,C} be a partition of E. List the elements of the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$."

Let me see if I got this right...because $\mathcal{C}$ is a partition of E, the smallest sigma algebra is the trivial one {$\emptyset$,E}?
What if $\mathcal{C}$ were not a partition?

Comment: How does $\{\emptyset, E\}$ contain _as members_ any of $A, B$ or $C$?

Comment: No, this is not right. The algebra you suggested does *not* contain $\mathcal C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{\varnothing,E\}$ does not contain $\mathscr{C}$, so it clearly cannot be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{C}$. That $\sigma$-algebra must contain $A,B,$ and $C$. It must also contain all countable unions of $A,B$, and $C$, so it must include $A\cup B$, $A\cup C$, $B\cup C$, and $A\cup B\cup C=E$, and it must include all of the complements $X\setminus Y$ with $X,Y\in\{A,B,C\}$, so in particular it must include $A\setminus A=\varnothing$. The list so far includes the following sets:

$$\varnothing,A,B,C,A\cup B,A\cup C,B\cup C,E\.$$

Is that collection of sets a $\sigma$-algebra? If so, it’s the smallest one containing $\mathscr{C}$, because (as we’ve just seen) every one of those sets **must** be in **any** $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: Ah, ok, so the smallest sigma-algebra then is {∅,A,B,C,{A,B},{A,C},{B,C},{A,B,C}}. What if C were not a partition of E?

Comment: @PrincessAmazia: Not quite: you’re missing one member.

Comment: Ah yes, of course: {∅,A,B,C,{A,B},{A,C},{B,C},{A,B,C},E}. Isn't this also the largest sigma-algebra at the same time? No, because we don't know how many elements are in A, B or C?

Comment: @PrincessAmazia: That’s better. It’s not the largest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{C}$ if $|E|>3$, because $\wp(E)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{C}$, and if $|E|>3$, then $|\wp(E)|>2^3=8$.

Comment: If $\mathcal{C}$ is a partition of E?

Comment: @PrincessAmazia: Sure: that just means that $A,B$, and $C$ are non-empty and pairwise disjoint, and their union is $E$. If $A$ is the set of negative reals, $B=\{0\}$, and $C$ is the set of positive reals, then $\{A,B,C\}$ is a partition of $\Bbb R$. And $\wp(\Bbb R)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R$ that contains $\{A,B,C\}$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Just one more thing: in this case, isn't it true that ℘(R) is at the same time the smallest and largest sigma-algebra containing {A,B,C}?

Comment: @PrincessAmazia: You’re welcome. No matter what $E$ is, if $\mathscr{C}=\{A,B,C\}$ is a partition of $E$, then the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{C}$ is the $8$-element $\sigma$-algebra $$\{\varnothing,A,B,C,A\cup B,A\cup C,B\cup C,E\}\;.$$ In particular, this is still true in my example; $\wp(\Bbb R)$ is another, **much** bigger $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: Ah, got it now :) Thanks!

Comment: @PrincessAmazia: *Whew!* :-) You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, $\{\emptyset, E\}$ does not contain your sets.

The use of $\{A,B,C\}$ being a partition, is that you can calculate their unions and intersections easily.